# How do I create columated data with VIM?

Tags: vim

I'd like to take a series of variable width lines

```
foo
bar
foobarbazquz
foobar
```

And append another column,

```
foo                asdf
bar                asdf
foobarbazquz       asdf
foobar             asdf
```

Does VIM provide any shortcuts to make this easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will probably be other good suggestions, but the one that you will want to look into immediately is the `'virtualedit'` option.  See:

```
:help 'virtualedit'
```

You probably want to just do:

```
:set virtualedit=all
```

Comment: Then look at `:help visual-block` to learn about operating on block of text, or in this case, blocks of space. For example, moving the cursor to the location of the first 'a' and typing `Ctrl-VjjjAasdf<Esc>` will insert all of those asdf's at once.

Comment: For what it's worth, you may also look at [textobj-word-column](https://github.com/coderifous/textobj-word-column.vim) plugin which will simplify column selection to typing just `vic`.